# Associative property in discrete 2D convolution

Tags: convolution, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

In CNN is tipically put on in cascade differents types of convolution layers, for example a 2D Convolution along with 2D Average Pooling. The convolution has the associative property:

$$(A*B)*C=A*(B*C)$$

In my case, $B$ and $C$ are the kernels of 2D Convolution and 2D Average pooling. Both are known and $B*C$ can be precomputed.

It's possible perform the convolution of kernels $K= B * C$ and later the convolution of $A*K$ instead of $(A*B)*C$?

Comment: I have not heard about average pooling, but I know that max-pooling which is popular, is not linear. If average pooling is just some linear averaging filter I think it should work.

Comment: Hi @mathreadler ! Yes, is a linear filter, specifically a "smoothing by averaging", a 2d convolution with the values of the filter equals to 1/(M·N) where M and N are the rows and cols from the kernel. In python I'm trying to perform the explained in my question but doesn't works, only the commutative property works correctly. Any suggestion?? Thanks!

Comment: In max-pooling there is a built-in sub-sampling. I suppose the same is the case in averaging pooling? If that is the case then you will need to regard the subsampling operation and when it happens. Before or after which of the filters.

Comment: In this case I don't use subsampling. I'm doing in this way only to check the associative property. I'm using Tensrflow/Keras libraries and my 2d convolution algorithm. My 2d conv algorithm works correctly when I don't use the associative property. I get a mean squared error of E-17. Thanks for the help @mathreadler !